# Como obter a cor do pixel tocado na tela no Android? (Sem usar imagens)

Tags: android, pixels

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação pra caligrafia e o que estou buscando é o seguinte:

Eu pretendo, usando um `TextView`, colocar as letras na tela e quero detectar se o usuário está tocando na tela dentro ou fora da área da letra/caractere (letra preta, fundo branco).

Todas as maneiras encontradas de fazer isso envolvem o uso de imagens e eu preciso de outra alternativa!

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Se sabe fazer com uma image(Bitmap) então só necessita um Bitmap que reproduza o TextView.

O método seguinte retorna uma imagem(bitmap) que representa o conteúdo da *view* passada.

```
public static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View view){

    //Cria um bitmap com as dimensões da view
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    //Cria um canvas para escrever no bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    //Pede à view que escreva o seu conteúdo no bitmap, usando o canvas
    //anteriormente criado.
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Note que o método só pode ser usado apenas após a "tree of views" ter sido criada, por exemplo no método `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

Exemplo de utilização para o seu caso: letras preto, fundo branco:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    Bitmap textViewBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                handleTouch(event.getX(), event.getY());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleTouch(float x, float y) {
        int pixel = textViewBitmap.getPixel((int)x, (int)y);
        if(pixel == Color.WHITE){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Branco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Preto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private static Bitmap getViewBitmap(View view){
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                view.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(textViewBitmap == null){
            textViewBitmap = getViewBitmap(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```