# Como criar bitmap de um Layout mantendo as dimensões iguais qualquer que seja a densidade da tela?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Tenho um arquivo de layout e estou passando ele para um *bitmap* que depois mando para uma impressora *bluetooth* em bytes.

De acordo com a resolução do celular, ele altera os tamanhos das fontes dos *textviews* - quanto maior a resolução, maior é a fonte.

Como faço para ele gerar o mesmo layout independentemente do dispositivo e sua resolução?

Meu código:

```
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(580, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(layout.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
    layout.buildDrawingCache(false);
    Bitmap sImagem = Bitmap.createBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache(false));
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

O 580 é a largura da impressão e está correta na impressora.
Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O número de pixeis que o Bitmap terá é função da densidade de pixeis da tela do dispositivo.

Assim, para que o tamanho da impressão seja independente da densidade, deve redimensionar o Bitmap em função da dimensão da view medida em `dp`.

Obtenha as dimensões do RelativeLayout recorrendo aos métodos `getWidth()` e `getHeight()`.

Os valores retornados por estes métodos estão em pixeis, converta-os para dp's usando este método:

```
public static int convertPixelsToDp(float pixels, Activity context){

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float density = metrics.density;
    return (int) Math.ceil(pixels / density);
}
```

Para obter o bitmap use o método `getViewBitmap()` desta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/192795/2541). Depois redimensione-o para as dimensões pretendidas usando por exemplo [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)).

Será algo assim:

```
int WidthDp = convertPixelsToDp(layout.getWidth());
int HeightDp = convertPixelsToDp(layout.getHeight());
Bitmap bitmap = getViewBitmap(layout);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, widthDp, heightDp, false);
```

O valor de `WidthDp` e `HeightDp` serão sempre os mesmos independentemente da densidade da tela do dispositivo.
Se as dimensões de `resizedBitmap` não forem adequadas à sua impressão(por serem pequenas ou grandes) aplique um factor aos valores `WidthDp` e `HeightDp` de forma a obter as dimensões que pretende.

Comment: ainda assim não funciona

Comment: Então tem que explicar melhor o problema.

Comment: neste link tenho a aplicação funcionando: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0LBOPuhnAPiOWZYM3N1NC10VEk e se for testado em celulares com resoluções diferentes você vai conseguir visualizar o bitmap diferente

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizei esta library para poder gerar um PDF de uma view. Ele tem um método que gera um bitmap para poder reaproveitar, a partir de uma view sem inflá-la. Acho que pode ajudar o problema:

```
AbstractViewRenderer page = new AbstractViewRenderer(context, R.layout.page1) {
    private String _text;

    public void setText(String text) {
        _text = text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initView(View view) {
        TextView tv_hello = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hello);
         tv_hello.setText(_text);
    }
};

page.setReuseBitmap(true);
```

Referência: https://github.com/HendrixString/Android-PdfMyXml

Comment: consigo exportar pro pdf mas na hora de gerar o bitmap, continua com o mesmo erro